# I can't install MySQL Server on Windows

Tags: installation, mysql

I asked this question on Stack Overflow as well, but decided I had to ask it here too. I have been trying for quite some time to install MySQL Server. I have read the documentation countless times, but can't even find a hint of what to do. It is really, really frustrating me.

I'm trying to download `MySQL Server` for Windows.

I downloaded the `Windows (x-86, 32-bit), ZIP Archive` from the MySQL website

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

When I extracted the archive to `C:`, I glanced at the contents.

A file was supposed to be created at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1`. I don't have a MySQL directory in Program Files. I also searched my computer for the file but couldn't find it.

Where is the file located, and how can I download it?

I'm viewing this file, from their website

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-archive.html

And am trying to work on step 2, `Creating an Option File`.

In that page, it talks about MySQL Server, which I cannot find.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: I believe posting the same question on multiple SE sites concurrently is discouraged (in which case you will likely get some feedback on that).  At the very least, please coordinate the two questions; if you get an answer on one site, post a reference to it on the other site so people don't continue to spend time reinventing the wheel.  Good luck.

Comment: I recommend you go for WAMP on windows instead of installing PHP, MySQL, and Apache separately.

Comment: If you have no experience installing MySQL server then it may be far easier for you to follow MehdiHaghgoo's advice and install, say, WAMP or XAMP. It'll sort everything out within a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you try installing the MySQL using its [MSI installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), which is much user friendly - where you can have a installation wizard with nice on-screen instruction, where you can simply install it by following the simple 1,2,3 steps ..

Comment: same error with msi installer, what may be the problem? tried both default and full install variant

Answer (score 2):

The archive is a compressed version of the MySQL directory structure. When you extract this archive you'll find that it creates a directory called `mysql-5.6.22-win32` inside whichever directory you told it to extract to.

If the ZIP file is downloaded to C:\Users\your_user_name\Downloads and you were to extract the archive into that directory, then a directory named `mysql-5.6.22-win32` would exist inside `C:\Users\your_user_name\Downloads`. This folder contains all the MySQL files.

You would then need to move that folder into the Program Files folder, giving the MySQL root directory a full path of `C:\Program Files\mysql-5.6.22-win32`

If you're having trouble with the installation process, I would recommend using the installation packages available from the web site, unless you have some specific need to use the ZIP archive.

NB: The exact name of the MySQL folder will differ depending upon the version you downloaded. Mine is `5.6.22-win32`, but yours may differ.